# Is there a faster way to work out this logic?

Tags: java, coding-style

The purpose of this assignment was the find the smallest and largest of the integer(User inputs 5 entries)

I am a beginner Java programmer with no prior experience. Is there an easier way to do this without a ton of if/else statements?

Forgive for the dirty code.

```
    //Scanner Object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
    int large;
    int small;

    System.out.print("Enter Num1: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Num2: ");
    num2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Num3: ");
    num3 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Num4: ");
    num4 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Num5: ");
    num5 = input.nextInt();

    //If/Else statements (SMALL)
    if (num1<num2 && num1<num3 && num1<num4 && num1<num5) {
        small = num1;

        }


    else if (num2<num1 && num2<num3 && num2<num4 && num2<num5) {
                small = num2;

                        }

    else if (num3<num1 && num3<num2 && num3<num4 && num3<num5) {
                small = num3;


    }

    else if (num4<num1 && num4<num2 && num4<num3 && num4<num5) {
                small = num4;


    }

    else {
        small = num5;

    }

    //Large

    if (num1>num2 && num1>num3 && num1>num4 && num1>num5) {
        large = num1;
    }

    else if (num2>num1 && num2>num3 && num2>num4 && num2>num5) {
                                        large = num2;
    }

    else if (num3>num1 && num3>num2 && num3>num4 && num3>num5) {
                large = num3;
    }

    else if (num4>num1 && num4>num2 && num4>num3 && num4>num5) {
                    large = num4;
    }

    else {
                large = num5;

            }


    //Display: Use printf when using a format limiter (%)

    System.out.printf("The smallest integer: %d\n", small);
    System.out.printf("The largest integer: %d\n", large);




    }// end of main

}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please add the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: This is absolutely not my homework.Got this from my brothers Android book lying around. I am thinking of diving into Android after i got the java basics down. The code i gave above works but i want to make it smaller. But, i can add the homework tag if thats going to help me.

Comment: Not necessary, Rony John. If it were actual homework, it's best to tag it that way so that someone doesn't just answer the entire question and the OP never learns anything.

Comment: I understand. I will do so next time.

Comment: @Caleb We have blacklisted [homework], for the reasons [discussed here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/removing-the-homework-tag).

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks -- didn't realize that Programmers had a different policy than SO on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use not only arrays like Caleb suggested, but also lists and sorting.

It is not the most efficient way, but it is, in my opinion, the fastest one to implement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int currentNumber;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Num"+(i+1)+": ");
        currentNumber=input.nextInt();
        numbers.add(currentNumber);
    }

    Collections.sort(numbers);

    System.out.printf("The smallest integer: %d\n", numbers.get(0));
    System.out.printf("The largest integer: %d\n", numbers.get(4));

}// end of main
```

**Edit:**

An alternative for millions of elements, improved with [jk.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/10563/jk)'s proposal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Integer min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int currentNumber;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Num"+(i+1)+": ");
        currentNumber=input.nextInt();

        max = Math.max(max, currentNumber);
        min = Math.min(min, currentNumber);
    }


    System.out.printf("The smallest integer: %d\n", min);
    System.out.printf("The largest integer: %d\n", max);

}// end of main
```

Comment: Thank You so Much!!!, I have so much to learn. Excited !!!

Comment: Sorting the whole array just to find mininum and maximum seems like a waste of resources to me.

Comment: @user281377: it could be, if the array contained a hundred million elements.  Otherwise, the shortest code wins.

Comment: what would have been an alternative if the array had millions of elements?

Comment: @RonyJohn I have added a more efficient version. No array or list is used, just two integers.

Comment: Awesome, Appreciate it. Good to see different and efficient ways to do this program.

Comment: @RonyJohn The differences is a factor of log n. That is, the time to scan through all the elements in an array is proportional to n, the number of elements in the array. We denote this O(n). Sorting an array is at least O(n log n) -- that is, the performance will be proportional to the product of the number of elements and the log of the number of elements. For small n, log n is quite small, so no big deal. As n increases, the difference between n and n log n becomes much more significant.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.

Comment: tbh i'd use Math.Max and min rather than coding my own branches. in which case the 'optimized' version will be as brief and arguably more descriptive than the sort version

Comment: @jk. I didn't think about that. I modified it! Thank you! :) Yes now it is more descriptive too!

Comment: As long as you know in advance how many integers you'll be dealing with, why not use a plain array instead of an ArrayList?

Comment: @compman the rational answer is that you are right and in the sorted version a simple `String[]` would have been more efficient. The irrational one is that in the past arrays have caused me so much trouble that I avoid them every time I can. :)

Answer (score 5):

There are definitely better ways to do that. Put the values in an array and then scan through the array looking keeping track of the smallest and largest values you find:

```
for (i in valueArray) {
    if (i < min) 
        min = i;
    if (i > max)
        max = i;
}
```

I'll leave that into real code up to you.

Comment: Thanks...Life would've been miserable without arrays. Appreciate your help Caleb.

Comment: Back in the '80s when I was < 10 years old, trying my bestest to program in gwbasic, I couldn't figure out arrays... what a shame.  `x23 = x24; x24 = x25` gaa;

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided good, generalized solutions. I would offer a variant of this which avoids sorting:

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.print("Enter Num1: ");
num1 = input.nextInt();
largest = Math.max(num1, largest)

System.out.print("Enter Num2: ");
num2 = input.nextInt();
largest = Math.max(num2, largest)

System.out.print("Enter Num3: ");
num3 = input.nextInt();
largest = Math.max(num3, largest)

System.out.print("Enter Num4: ");
num4 = input.nextInt();
largest = Math.max(num4, largest)

System.out.print("Enter Num5: ");
num5 = input.nextInt();
largest = Math.max(num5, largest)
```

This is basically the same as Caleb's suggestion, but without the enumeration and done along the way.